# cocos2dx with box2d contactlistener doesnt work

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

im using box2d 2.3.1physics engine in my cocos2dx v4 project. My polygon shapes are created using physics editor. all colliding itself properly but contact listener doesnt log contacts.

this is my contactlistener header defined in helloworld.h

> class MyContactListener : public b2ContactListener
> {
> private :
> void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
> void EndContact(b2Contact* contact);
> void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold);
> void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse);
>
> };

this is my contactlistener implementation in helloworld.cpp

> void MyContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {
> std::cout << "BeginContactn\n";
>
> }

> void MyContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact) {
>
> std::cout << "EndContact\n";
>
> }

> void MyContactListener::PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) {
>
> std::cout << "PreSolve\n";
>
> }

> void MyContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse) {
>
> std::cout << "PostSolve\n";
>
> }

> MyContactListener myContactListenerInstance;

and my contactlistener assignment to world (in helloworld.cpp init )

> _rootWorld->getb2World()->SetContactListener(&myContactListenerInstance);

all works **but it doesnt log collion contacts**

my bodies category and bitmask values are

body A : bitmask : 63, category: 1

body B : bitmask : 63, category: 2

body C : bitmask : 63, category: 4

body D : bitmask : 63, category: 8

body E : bitmask : 63, category: 16

body F : bitmask : 63, category: 32

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

i solved problem by changing std::cout to log("..."), i guess cocos2dx engine changes std::cout behaviour so I doesnt print anything